# Error on launching the "App Store"

Tags: appcenter, apt, google-chrome, repositories

I get the following error when I launch the **AppCentre**. It reads

`E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'`

I had installed Chrome via Eddy. When I encountered this error, I uninstalled it.

But I could not get rid of this error. I have attached a screenshot of how it displays. How do I get rid of it?

[image: Error on launching "App Store"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `AppCentre` can't handle that kind of user interaction

That message was a normal user interaction asking if you accept the change from `Google Inc` to `Google LLC` in the repo's config

Anyone using `apt` through terminal could answer that without any issue but if the GUI, in this case `AppCentre`, wasn't able to and by default treated like an error you see that message. A wrong message because was not an error, the error is on `AppCentre`

To continue without that message, open a terminal and use this command

```
$ sudo apt update
```

there you'll be asked the question I told you above (Yes/No question).
Answer `Yes` and then you can continue using `AppCentre` as usual

---

There's no need to remove Google's repo, there's no problem there. Also because this isn't an error you can install Chrome back safely if you want/need

I also recommend you to report the error on `AppCentre`'s Github page

https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues

Answer (score 0):

Try running this terminal command

```
sudo apt update
```

If this does not fix the App Center warning, try removing the repository from your system.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save
sudo apt update
```

This means you will not longer get updates for google chrome. You will have to reinstall google chrome to get updates. You can do this via third party repository or by downloading and installing the .deb file directly from google.